# Turn existing column into a primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create table emp
 (
 emp_id int,
 emp_name varchar(40) not null,
 emp_address varchar(35) not null,
 )
```

Now I need to add primary key to emp_id . I tried using alter query

```
alter table emp add constraint   emp_id  primary key
```

its showing error as

> Table level constraint does not specify column list, table 'emp'.

Comment: Consider: constraints have names and are separate entities; they are not columns. So it's `add constraint constraint_name ..`, etc.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE emp
ADD PRIMARY KEY (emp_id)
```

OR

```
ALTER TABLE emp
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_empID PRIMARY KEY (emp_id)
```

Comment: ADD CONSTRAINT x PRIMARY KEY is cleaner, since you can name the PK, instead of letting SQL Server add a cryptic random name to the all-important Primary Key