# SQL query error from MySQL to MS SQL server

Tags: mysql, sql-server

When I import the following SQL query from MySQL to MS SQL server, a warning is appeared"Table level constraint does not specify column list, table 'Mark'."
Does anyone can help me solve this problem??

The following is a part of the whole query.(It was generated by MySQL workbench

```
CREATE TABLE Mark (
  student_id INT NOT NULL,
  exam_id INT NOT NULL,
  subject_id INT NOT NULL,
  mark VARCHAR(2) NULL,
  INDEX Student_id_idx ON Mark(student_id),
  INDEX Subject_id_idx ON Mark(subject_id),
  INDEX Exam_id_idx ON Mark(exam_id),
  CONSTRAINT exam_id
    FOREIGN KEY (exam_id)
    REFERENCES Exam (exam_id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT student_id
    FOREIGN KEY (student_id)
    REFERENCES Student (student_id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT subject_id
    FOREIGN KEY (subject_id)
    REFERENCES Subject (subject_id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Comment: To get you beyond this point, I'd attempt the following...
1. Create the table
2. Use 'alter table' statements to add/effect the foreign key assignments
Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23075260/turn-existing-column-into-a-primary-key and 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Mark] (
  [student_id] [int] NOT NULL,
  [exam_id] [int] NOT NULL,
  [subject_id] [int] NOT NULL,
  [mark] [varchar](2) NULL,

  FOREIGN KEY ([Exam_id]) REFERENCES [Exam]([Exam_id]),
  FOREIGN KEY ([Student_Id]) REFERENCES [Student]([Student_Id])
  FOREIGN KEY ([subject_id]) REFERENCES [Subject]([subject_id])
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```